# Can't access resource file in subfolder with gradle configuration

Tags: java, gradle, resources

I'm working on a javafx project with gradle in Intellij.
In a ResourceHelper class I make 2 calls :

- ResourceHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("pic.png")
- ResourceHelper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("icon/app.png")

where pic.png and icon folder are both in src/main/resources.

When I use default configuration (by clicking on green arrow in main class) all is working fine but when I choose gradle run configuration only first resource is loaded ; if I move app.png in resource folder it's ok, so the problem is accessing to resource subfolder and I can't figure out why... 'I also tried to set "/icon/app.png", "./icon/app.png", "icon\app.png", ...)

Can someone tell me why ?

Thanks

Comment: *I also tried to set "/icon/app.png"* That is the correct path to your resource. If it's not working, I'm not sure why

Comment: It's not working